# How to put my game made in pygame into a website like google sites or a private domain

Tags: javascript, python, pygame

Is it possible? I want to put my game on a website so students and presenters could access it freely as it is an educational resource. Should I use javascript and buy a domain? What's the cheapest option?

Comment: well, since its coded in python using pygame which is not for online stuff, there isn't much you can do. In repl.it you can create a pygame project and people can use an online python environment to play it.

Comment: @MannanBhardwaj Then what language should I use to create the game? I can just migrate it over...

Comment: Javascript probably as said in @TarunR's answer.

Comment: In web browser you have to use JavaScript or something what can be translated to JavaScript - ie. CoffeScript. There is also [Brython](https://brython.info/) - Python interpreter created in JavaScript - so it can run some Python code in browser. Or [transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/examples) which can convert to JavaScript. But better use JavaScript libraries to create web games. There is also tools [GodotEngine](https://godotengine.org/) which can create for different device/systems and have many extra tools - and it use scripting language with syntax similar to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you can't use Pygame for website games. Also pygame is clunky, slow and old so I don't recommend it. Instead just use JavaScript with canvas. The logic is really similar to PyGame, and you just need to learn some basic JS syntax.